# CRUD delete using modal form

Tags: php, pdo, bootstrap-modal, crud

I am creating a CRUD using PHP extension with PDO, and I want to create a confirmation for registry deletion using Bootstrap modals, but I don't know how I can pass the ID information to the modal to delete, how can I do it?

**index.php**

```
<tbody>
                <?php
                $pdo = DB::connect();
                $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM people");
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th scope='row'>" . $row["id"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["first_name"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["last_name"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["notes"] . "</td>";
                    if ($row["allowed"]) {
                        echo "<td>" . "✔" . "</td>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<td>" . "✗" . "</td>";
                    };
                    echo "<td>";
                    // modal trigger
                    echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
</tbody>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Do you want to delete this registry?</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this section add your ID

```
echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' onclick='$(".delete_id").val('".$row["id"]."')'>Delete</button>";
```

Then in modal add an hidden input field like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" class="delete_id">
```

Include jQuery before this function. You also need to have a delete file to pass that variable. After the request was success you could re-render the HTML.

```
function deleteRecord() {
   var id = $(".delete_id").val();

    $.ajax({
    url:"/delete.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{
      id: id,
    },
    success:function(response) {
    
   },
   });
}
```

After we have stored the value of the ID we can delete it

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteRecord()">Yes</button>
```

Hope this was helpful